# In a magic system where smoking live beings boosts your power, is it probable that lung cancer spreads inevitably?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems

The questions purpose is to ask if anyone can think of how much dangerous/toxic it is to smoke flesh, to the point where abusing this act would make the possibility of getting lung cancer a bigger threat than the boost you are getting.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the kind of being, and how exactly you would smoke it? Different beings, different makeup of flesh.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No. That makes only probable that people reading your rulebook will have some ideas, what did you use to invent such ideas.

Comment: Does blue pill gives you HIV? Does sunscreen gives you skin cancer? Does fast food give you diabetes? Does soda drinks give you cavity? Does driving kills? Just because the numbers of such incidents is high doesn't mean there's a correlation between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To a great extent this depends on context not currently provided in your question. Is everyone a magic user, and a notable percentage of them smoke to speed their daily commute in their magic carts? Then yes, regularly inhaling smoke will probably increase cancers and lung ailments to a point where it is (eventually) observable, and may come to be considered a bad trade to most.

On the other hand, if magic users are a rarity, and/or the boosts they are using are more commonly risky summons or juicing for magical combat? Then even a highly increased risk of cancer over time simply doesn't show up as a terribly frequent cause of death, because it's a small population prone to dying due to other things first. Observe how long it took modern science to identify various carcinogens in our own world. And Big Meat might have lobbyists (and/or magical assassins) discouraging anyone from getting excessively epidemiological in your world, as well.

In terms of the specific dangers of "smoked meat", that's up to you and your world. Maybe magic smoke is particularly toxic. [Real world meatsmoke](https://www.columbiadoctors.org/news/do-grilled-foods-cause-cancer) is certainly not a good place to leave your lungs long term, especially on a daily basis. But it isn't so remarkably carcinogenic that it's particularly high on any lists of risk factors, either. We still grill, and the only stat bonus it grants is to flavor.

This question touches on a theme that appears common in many worldbuilding questions: "If doing [thing] has a risk [x] that's greater than benefit [y], why would anyone do [thing]?" It's important to remember that unless your world explicitly lets its inhabitants read the strategy guide, [x] and [y] are devilishly difficult to know in any meaningful way. Noticing long term health impacts requires very good recordkeeping and good communication, all over a large enough group that your statistics aren't completely boggled because an ill-timed squabble between nobles resulted in premature amateur autopsies for a substantial portion of your subject group. Even assessing the value of the benefit is subject to enormous social pressures and individual cognitive fallacies. Look at all the absurd and obviously wrong things that groups do today. Other groups, I mean. Not whatever group you may be a part of, they are obviously entirely rational and not prone to confirmation bias etc.